# Get Telegram API_ID and API_HASH programmatically

Tags: telegram, telethon, pyrogram

I'm trying to figure out how to get my Telegram API_ID and API_HASH using either Telethon or Pyrogram but can't seem to find anything on the internet so far. In my program, a user can sign up to Telegram programmatically (without having to use their real phone number) but for them to be able to do anything an API_ID and API_HASH are required but then the phone verification site won't give code for that old number since it's one time only.

One solution that comes to mind, is scraping the telegram site and simulating the log in, then reading the code sent to the client and using that to scrape the API_ID and API_HASH from the web page but that sounds like too much work right now as i'd love a simpler approach.

I hope this is as clear as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking there's no need to do this. When developing a program, the developer embeds their own API ID and hash into the program. Users of the program do not need to be aware of the existence of these values (leave alone forcing them to use their own).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Telegram's MTPROTO API Credentials are bound to a specific account, they represent an Application like Telegram Android, Telegram Desktop or Telegram WebK/WebZ. You can use the same pair of API_ID and API_HASH across multiple applications.

Comment: To clarify further: the `API_ID` and `API_HASH` are those of the *developer*, not the *user* (although the user *can* be that same developer, it doesn't *have* to be). If You develop something with these libraries, it is Your API ID/hash that you must provide, since your users should not need to register their own application to use your program!

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. But another question I have is can I perform actions on multiple accounts like the way it's done in Toologram? Or would those accounts need their own api_id and api_hash for certain api calls?

Comment: I'm doing a research project for education where a client (user) can create N accounts and use each account created to access Telegram's API to perform tasks like backing up a supergroup.